# How to combine 2 scripts together?

Tags: python, linux, hash, scripting, hashcode

Well i have 2 different scripts that i wrote 
The first one is just getting an md5 hash from all files that are .exe 
The other script is some agent who check's every 3 seconds if their is new files
in the directory .
now i need to make the agent check the files and also print every md5

this are my scripts :

```
import os, time
path_to_watch = "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1"
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
  time.sleep (3)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added: print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
  if removed: print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
  before = after
```

And the second one who checks for md5

```
import glob
import os
import hashlib

work_path = '/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/'
filenames = glob.glob("/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/*.exe" )
if len(os.listdir(work_path)) > 0:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
            data = inputfile.read()
            print hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
else:
    print '0'
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the first file's functionality into functions and then importing it as a module?

Comment: well no i didn't try that

Comment: do you want to execute both the script at the same time or you want to find the new files and then get md5 hashes for each of the new files found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reducing the iteration from the hash generation, wrapping it into a function and call it when a new file is found:

```
import time
import glob
import os
import hashlib

def md5(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
        print filename, hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()

path_to_watch = "."
before = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
while 1:
    time.sleep(3)
    after = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
    if added:
        print "Added: ", ", ".join(added)
        for filename in added:
            md5(filename)
    if removed: 
        print "Removed: ", ", ".join(removed)
    before = after
```

Also stripped some unnecessary dict stuff from the code.

I suggest you take it as a challenge to reduce the number of statements and the number of data transformations to a minimum while keeping the function of the script. At the same time it might be worth a look to the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) ;)